# How to return objects name JS?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the objects name in JS. I am trying to avoid doing loops for better code reading.
As I am new to the JS code I am not sure what to do.

```
const collection = [
        {
        name: 'foo',
        value: 12,
        },
        {
        name: 'bar',
        value: 5,
        },
    ]

const fa = (collection) = {
        //theName should return just the name value so 'bar'
        let theName = Object.keys(collection).find(value => value < 10).name;
        console.log(theName);
}
```

Thanks to anyone who could help.

Comment: What should be your desired result/output?

Comment: `fa = collection => collection.find(({ value }) => value < 10)?.name` ?

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). I'm afraid it's not at all clear what you're asking here.

Comment: Thanks. I´ve edited the post and allready I see answers that were needed! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 4):

You could get from the array the ones who have a certain value and the get the names from the array.

```js
const
    collection = [{ name: 'foo', value: 12 }, { name: 'bar', value: 5 }],
    fa = collection => collection
        .filter(({ value }) => value < 10)
        .map(({ name }) => name);

console.log(fa(collection));
```

If you want only a single/first result, you could find the object and get the name from it with an [optional chaining operator `?.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to prevent using a property on `undefined`.

```js
const
    collection = [{ name: 'foo', value: 12 }, { name: 'bar', value: 5 }],
    fa = collection => collection
        .find(({ value }) => value < 10)
        ?.name;

console.log(fa(collection));
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably wanted this:

```js
const collection = [
        {
        name: 'foo',
        value: 12,
        },
        {
        name: 'bar',
        value: 5,
        },
    ]

const fa = (collection) => {
    let theName = collection.find(obj => obj.value < 10).name;
    console.log(theName);
}
fa(collection)
```

Comment: yes, but use `?.name` instead of `.name` in case it's not there

Comment: @georg you're right, but intentionally I didn't used optional chaining operator, since it's still quite modern feature, and we also expect that every collection will have name and value.